# How to integrate my app delegate and View controller code in KONY app?

Tags: ios, watchkit, watch, watchos-2, temenos-quantum

I'm developing a watch application using Xcode. And the actual iOS app is already implemented using Kony. And now I'm trying to add this watch app to the iOS app.

But the problem is the IOS app is developed in Kony. And I have written some code in Xcode with in `AppDelegate.m` and `ViewController.m(RootViewController)` of IOS bundle to communicate with watch and pass some data.So Everything is working fine.For this I created a new application and I did that phone to watch communication and watch app implementation.

Now the difficult part is I have to integrate or copy the code whatever I have written in sample app using Xcode to that Kony application.

Means Now I have to add this `AppDelegate.m` and `ViewController.m` code in to Kony Code which is developed by Kony IDE.

So how to integrate whatever i have done in Xcode build to Kony build ?

Answer (score 1):

## Problem Statement

How to integrate my app delegate and View controller code in KONY app?

## Answer

We understand that you are integrating AppDelegate methods in Kony App.

Using Kony you can implement AddDelegate methods using following steps.

1. Kindly replace the attached AppDelegateExtension folder into your VMAppWithKonylib.xcodeproj
2. Add the statements in the didFinishLaunchingW/Users/kh1949/Desktop/AppDelegateExtension 2.zipithOptions method present in SampleAppDelegate.m file.

Regards,
Guru Murthy**strong text**